# Schemaform hide field **value** if it equals to X

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

i have a form that is being loaded with the use of `schema-form`, in that form i have a field `MaxCards`his value is the value from db, and it can be null in the server-side i transformed null to `-1`

```
MaxCards = domainColumn.MaxCards.HasValue ? domainColumn.MaxCards.Value : -1
```

When the value `-1` is loaded i dont want to show it in the form UI, instead i want to show an empty string.

[image]

**How can I achieve it?**

this is how i load the form: (Key: MaxCards is the field that i am talking about)

```
    vm.form = [{
        key: 'Name',
        readonly: false
    }, {
        key: 'MaxCards',
        readonly: false,
        fieldHtmlClass: "editColumnModel-maxCards"
    }, {
        key: 'Description',
        readonly: false,
        type: 'textarea'
    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try, replacing your -1 values, though I would suggest you to return blank space from your service/controller instead of -1 (null) if the type safety is not a concern.

```
{{ domainColumn.MaxCards.Value.replace('-1', ' ') }}
```

Or

```
$scope.domainColumn.MaxCards.Value.replace('-1', ' ');
```

I have not tested this nor I am sure what values your code returns, so please feel free to tweak this code a little.

Comment: Yeah, if you can that would be great, else use any of the replace functions as suggested above. try this I am sure you'll be able to resolve this issue.

Comment: I prefer to change in only in the ui of it can be done, instead of changing it though the scope..

Comment: {{ domainColumn.MaxCards.Value.replace('-1', ' ') }} option is at UI level

Comment: this is just before the DOM element is presented to client